# Click event not working on IE9 in Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, button, click

I am trying to add click event on button But it is not working on IE9.

```
$('#proceed_btn').click(function(){ alert('test');
        handleWelcomePage();
        $('a.prev').show();
    });
```

above is JS code & below is button code.

```
<button id="proceed_btn" type="submit" data-theme="a">Proceed</button>
```

Comment: show us a little more of your code. When are you binding this event?

Comment: alert is coming or not

Comment: this is the only code I am using..

Comment: No alert is not cuming..

Comment: If you are using jQuery Mobile, click event MUST be bound inside a existing page event.

Comment: please try by putting all the code in comment except alert

Comment: do you have jquery library added?

Comment: Yes I have added jquery library..

Comment: I have tried with alert only but not working..

Comment: no way this is the only code. Alert must be shown. Maybe javascript is disabled in your browser?

Comment: You need to put this in $(document).ready(){}

Comment: javascript is not disabled

Comment: function is written in $(document).ready(){}

Comment: and you told you post all code :D i bet bunch of other code is missing.

Comment: $(document).ready(){} is your problem, jQuery Mobile should not be used with $(document).ready(){} , read more about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600 .

Comment: wait a minute..this is a submit button?

Comment: I have tried with .on('pageinit', function() but it is not working..

Comment: it is not a submit button.. on the click of this button another hidden DIV is get viewed..

Comment: it is working on all other Browsers perfectly..

Comment: check this example http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Zd9Ya/

Comment: we are resolving issues regarding IE 8 & above version..

Comment: My code is working on all other browsers.. Omar your code is also working on other browsers but it is not working on IE9

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
   $('#proceed_btn').on("change", function(){ 
        alert('test');
        handleWelcomePage();
        $('a.prev').show();
    });
});
```

Try the code above